# How can i delete char or int from a string which have both int and char example given below

Tags: python

I have one long string "M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB

out put should look like this:

```
"370153"
```

or

```
"M.tuberculosisHRv|Rvc|ptbB<b"
```

thanks

Comment: You could use a [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). How did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'[0-9]', '', 'M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB')
'M. tuberculosis HRv|Rvc|ptbB'
>>> re.sub(r'[^0-9]', '', 'M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB')
'370153'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
In [4]: ''.join([x for x in s if x.isdigit()])
Out[4]: '370153'
```

and the fastest way is:

```
In [4]: ''.join((x for x in s if x.isdigit()))
Out[4]: '370153'
```

Comment: Why are you using a list comprehension instead of a generator expression? I think the latter is much more appropriate here, almost certainly faster, and shorter to boot.

Comment: No, I mean [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions). You can simply drop the brackets to make your program use them. This means that Python won't senselessly allocate a list for your results, iterate once over it, and then throw it away.

Comment: @phihag A generator expression is slower using Python 2.7 according to `python -m timeit "''.join(ch for ch in 'M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB' if ch.isdigit())"`

Comment: You are right, generator much faster. Thank you!

Comment: I found that using list comprehension took 80% of the time that a generator expression took, at least in this example. I'm not sure how the timing would change for strings of increasing length though?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe You're right, they are not faster. In my tests, both variants seem to have about the same runtime. In any case, the main argument for generator expressions is simplicity and showing the intent of the code.

Comment: @phihag You may find that something based on `filter` is even faster, e.g. maybe `python -m timeit -s "import operator; f = operator.methodcaller('isdigit'); s = 'M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB'" "filter(f, s)"` is even more efficient for you.

Comment: Sadly enough, in Python 2.x a solution based on `translate` seems to be by far the fastest for me, try, `python -m timeit -s "import string; allChars = string.maketrans('', ''); allButDigits = allChars.translate(allChars, string.digits)" "'M. tuberculosis H37Rv|Rv0153c|ptbB'.translate(allChars, allButDigits)"`.